# A Better Way to Define a Read-Only Property in Vala

Tags: properties, readonly, vala

Reading through the Vala docs, I see there's a shorthand for defining a property:

```
public class Person : Object {
    public int age { get; set; default = 32; }
}
```

I tried to define a read-only variable by removing `set;` from the list, but I get a compilation error that the getter must be defined. I've resorted to using the longhand form:

```
public class Person : Object {
    private int _age = 32;

    public int age {
        get { return _age; }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use the shorthand notation to with defining a setter?

Answer (score 8):

No.  If you could just do `public int age { get; }`, where would the value come from?

What you probably want is:

```
public class Person : Object {
  public int age { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I set a default value like `public int age { get; default = 32; }`. My assumption was that Vala would be smart and set the initial value but never expose a setter method.

Comment: But you're also going to want a way to set the property, otherwise `public const int AGE = 32;` would make more sense.  You can use a getter with an implementation without a setter because you could be computing the value (e.g., from an age_in_days field) or getting it from anywhere else.  However, with an automatic getter I really can't imagine a situation where it makes sense.

Comment: In that case, the value could come from bypassing the (non-existing) setter by letting the owning class directly access the backing variable. This is not how it works in Vala, but I would prefer it that way. While working, `private set` looks a bit redundant to me.